# user reamins login in social networking site using my application

Tags: integration, linkedin-api

I want to develop an app. I want to integrate linkedIn account with my app. As the user logs in my app he one authenticate his linkedIn account and next time whenever he logs in he automatically login with linkedIn also
How I can achieve this. 
either saving the id and password of user or the only access token???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After allowing a user to connect with LinkedIn (via their [OAuth API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)), you need to store the LinkedIn OAuth token in your database, separate from the user's session. Then when the user logs in again you can just get the token from your database and continue making authenticated requests to LinkedIn.

Comment: Yes the same goes for Twitter and any other Oauth service. All your oauth tokens would be associated with the appropriate user